# React/ ESLint - JSX props should not use arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm currently creating a component in react and i'm using the ES Lint rule `react/jsx-no-bind`. My issue here is that I want to be able to pass a parameter to my components function. Here is the code I would like to use to be able to do so:

```
class LanguageDropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  changeLanguage = (lang) => {
    console.log(lang)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.languages.map(lang => <button onCLick={() => this.changeLanguage(lang)}>{lang}</button>)}
      </div>
    )
  }

...
```

This pulls up the ESlint error:

> JSX props should not use arrow functions

I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this without using an arrow function or using `.bind()`. I could add a data-attribute to the button element and then just pass in the event into the `changeLanguage` function and fetch the attribute using event.target() but this doesn't feel like it's the way it should be approached in React.

Can someone tell me what would be the correct way?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053846/2823226

Comment: If I may, why do you use the rule `no-bind`?

Comment: no-bind is part of the es lint config i inherited. I believe its best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor button into its own component:

```
class MyButton extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    language: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  onClick = () => console.log(this.props.language);

  render() {
    const {language} = this.props;
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick} type="submit">
        {language}
      </button>);
  }
}
```

and then in your LanguageDropDown class, use MyButton like this:

```
class LanguageDropdown extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.languages.map(lang => <MyButton key={lang} language={lang}/>)}
      </div>
    )
  }

  ...
}
```

A couple of additional things:

- You have a typo onCLick should be onClick
- You need a key for repeated items

Comment: Seems like the only logical option! Thanks for the other points, was just trying to post minimal code :)

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.
    here I tried by taking the value into the state, same can be tried using props.
    class LanguageDropdown extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {languages:['telugu','hindi','english']};
       // this.changeLanguage = this.changeLanguage.bind(this);
      }

```
  changeLanguage(event,lang){
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log('change lang: '+JSON.stringify(lang));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.languages.map(lang => <button onClick={(event)=>this.changeLanguage(event,lang)}>{lang}</button>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


render(<LanguageDropdown />, document.getElementById('root'));

when you bind the handler in the onClick event where you are passing the value to the handler, then we have to pass that value from the event and collect it to get that value.
```