# React Best Practices: If we can't use arrow functions in JSX onChange( ), how can we pass in custom arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for an elegant alternative to arrow functions in React components.

[Apparently in React](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36) 
, using arrow functions in a parent container leads to performance issues in children. This is because anonymous arrow functions are considered "new" function instances, so every parent `render()` causes pure components to re-render (if said arrow function is passed down).

I personally loved the usage of arrow functions for their readability. Take for example the below code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.users.map(user => {
            return (
               <User key={user.id} user={user} onClick={(e) => this.deleteUser(e, user.id)} />;
            )
          }}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
}
```

It is very clear where `this.deleteUser()` gets its arguments from. But compare that to the way it "should be done":

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import User from './User';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Cory' }, 
        { id: 2, name: 'Meg' }, 
        { id: 3, name: 'Bob'}
      ],
    };
  }

  deleteUser = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { 
        users: prevState.users.filter(user => user.id !== id) 
      };
    });
  };

  renderUser = user => {
    return <User key={user.id} user={user} onClick={this.deleteUser} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.users.map(this.renderUser)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Why?? This is so much less readable. How do you know `this.renderUser` gets `user` passed in as an argument? How do you know `this.deleteUser` gets `userId` pass in as an argument?

What alternatives are there? An existing [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651425/react-eslint-jsx-props-should-not-use-arrow-functions) proposes to move children into their own components and pass in arguments via props, but sometimes you don't want to get so modular.

Is there no sane solution as elegant as the arrow function? Or is our best hope to wait until the React Team patches this for sake of readability and community adoption?

Comment: If you use latest version with react-hooks, you can use arrow function because hooks avoid the problems caused by classes and the ineffeciency due to arrow functions is much less. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335950/performance-penalty-of-creating-handlers-on-every-render/53336060#53336060

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After investigating more, the compromise I was looking for can be achieved with a JS function returning a function.

From this:

```
<div onClick={(e) => this.doSomething(e, 'abc')}></div>
```

To this:

```
doSomething = (param) => (e) => {
   console.log(param) // 'abc'
   console.log(e.target.value) // 'hello world'
}
<input onChange={this.doSomething('abc')}></div>
```

Still not as elegant and readable as `<input onChange={(e) => this.doSomething(e, 'abc')}></div>` in my opinion, but works well enough.

Comment: This solution does get around the linting rule, but it does not solve the performance problem of having a new function instance passed down which the rule is supposed to protect against and adds needless complexity. `// eslint-disable-next-line reac/jsx-no-bind` has the same effect.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you know this.renderUser gets user passed in as an argument? How do you know this.deleteUser gets userId pass in as an argument?

Let's take `this.state.users.map(this.renderUser)` for example. As you know your `this.state.users` is an array. Which indicates that `map` is the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. The function signature looks like this (in its reduced form)

```
someArray.map(currentItem => {
    // Handle your item here
});
```

As you can see, it take callback. That callback itself can take up to 3 arguments (we only need one here). Now looking back at your `this.renderUser` we can see that it's also a function that takes one argument.

We can then use it as a callback for our previous `map` function. If we just *copy/paste* its implementation, we will have something like this

```
this.state.users.map(user => {
    return <User key={user.id} user={user} onClick={this.deleteUser} />;
});
```

So when you write `this.state.users.map(this.renderUser)`, you're doing the same thing as if *copy/pasting* your function. The argument `user` is the same one in both cases

Comment: That works, but I'm looking for a more explicit way. With arrow functions you can see whats being passed in every time, which lets me be clear on passing in additional arguments. For example, `<div onClick={(e) => this.doSomething(e, 'Steven', 'arbitrary')}></div>`